# ¿Cómo evitar que se abra la barra de edición de Android?

Tags: javascript, android, css, cordova, phonegap

Estoy pasando un e-book a una app desarrollada en Cordova/PhoneGap. Por defecto, las aplicaciones de Cordova tienen el siguiente CSS que hace que los usuarios no pueda seleccionar texto o imágenes:

```
-webkit-touch-callout: none;    /* prevent callout to copy image, etc when tap to hold */
-webkit-text-size-adjust: none; /* prevent webkit from resizing text to fit */
-webkit-user-select: none;      /* prevent copy paste, to allow, change 'none' to 'text' */
```

Para poder seleccionar texto, redefino el valor de `user-select` a `text`, como por ejemplo para el elemento `#content`:

```
#content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
  user-select: text !important;
  -webkit-user-select: text !important;
}
```

Esto funciona sin problemas, pero tiene un inconveniente: al seleccionar texto se muestra la barra de edición de Android (ver imagen abajo en azul claro) y yo no quiero que se muestren porque tendré los míos propios.

[image: controles de edición de android al seleccionar texto]

¿Hay alguna manera de evitar que esos controles por defecto aparezcan? Preferiría una solución basada en Cordova/PhoneGap, pero si la única manera de hacerlo es con Java, estaría abierto a esa posibilidad.

Comment: tienes acceso al webview de Android ?

Comment: Estoy usando cordova para desarrollar la aplicación. Creo que técnicamente sí podría modificar el MainActivity.java, por lo que me valdría algo con Java, pero estaba buscando una solución más centrada en cordova si fuera posible.

Comment: pues lo que encontré fue esto , pero creo que ya lo tienes: * {
   -webkit-user-select: none;
}      que versión de android estas probando

Comment: Eso evita que se pueda seleccionar. Yo quiero que sí se pueda seleccionar, pero que en lugar de aparecerme los controles de copia/seleccionar todo/compartir/buscar, quiero mostrar los míos propios.

Comment: aquí encontré algo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107651/android-disable-text-selection-in-a-webview

Comment: @diegoveloper Gracias. Voy a echarle un ojo.

Comment: No se si a alguien en verdad le funciona -webkit-user-select: none;  , recuerdo desde android 2.1 esto nunca ha funcionado.

Comment: @Jorgesys el user-select funciona bien. Y puedo seleccionar texto solo en la sección que quiero. El problema es que me sale el menú contextual de android y no quiero eso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se supone que hay métodos por medio del css para prevenir esto los cuales personalmente no me funcionaron, pero del lado del WebView puedes evitar el Long Click , y deshabilitar que sea "clickable":

```
myWebView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    return true;
}
});

myWebView.setLongClickable(false);
```